# How to send the correct ID to the controller with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How do I add code to the input button so that the value of the Id is sent to the Controller?

I have eight images. Then I click on the id of 116, open this image.

[image: images]

When I click on the biggest photo, Open a bootstrap modal for me.

[image: modal]

This action tag form is written to this ID `120`, While I have selected ID `116`.

`http://localhost:8000/admin/products/4/galleries/120`

```html
@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-10 p-5 pt-2">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('products.galleries.store', $product->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
            @csrf
        </form>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="mx-auto" id="showImage">
                    <img src="{{ asset("storage/{$gallery->image}") }}" class="img-fluid cursor-pointer" onclick="deleteImage('{{ $gallery->id }}', '{{ route('products.galleries.delete', [$product->id, $gallery->id]) }}')">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                @foreach($galleries as $gallery)
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <img src="{{ asset("storage/{$gallery->image}") }}" class="img-fluid cursor-pointer" onclick="showImage('{{ asset("storage/{$gallery->image}") }}', '{{ $gallery->id }}')"><br><div class="text-center text-danger">{{ $gallery->id }}</div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="delete" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="delete" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <form action="{{ route('products.galleries.delete', [$product->id, $gallery->id]) }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">This action is not reversible.</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Are you sure you want to delete the image?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection

@push('script')
    <script src="{{ asset('themes/js/dropzone.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        function showImage(url, id) {
            let route = "'"+'{{ route('products.galleries.delete', [$product->id, $gallery->id]) }}'+"'";
            let image = '<img src='+url+' onclick="deleteImage('+id+','+route+')" class="img-fluid cursor-pointer" />';
            $('#showImage').html(image);
        }

        function deleteImage(id, url) {
            $('#delete').modal(id, url);
        }
    </script>
@endpush
```

web.php

```
Route::post('products/{product}/galleries/{gallery}', 'GalleryController@delete')->name('products.galleries.delete');
```

Comment: Please share your route aslo

Comment: @A.ANoman I updated my post